# How to use URL resolver

Tags: xbmc, kodi

Is it simple how urlresolver works? How do I use it in my addon? Do I just import it and it's going to work or do I have to call it somehow and give the embedded link I get from the web site?

Can someone give a clear understanding or point me to a good post that explains it and show how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The URLResolver Kodi add-on works in the background of Kodi (called a dependency) to decode file hosts in order to play the root movie or TV video stream. If you are new to Kodi, you probably notice that a lot of add-ons use the same filehosts – Gvideo, clicknupload, zshare, dizilab are some of the popular ones. The URLResolver Kodi add-on knows how to navigate through these hosts, clicking through captcha’s and virtually retrieving the streaming file which you see in Kodi.
URLResolver is automatically installed with any add-on that uses it, so you probably have the latest Kodi URLResolver update on your box without event knowing it.

For more information visit following link:

- http://bestforkodi.com/url-resolver-the-most-used-addon-that-stays-in-the-background/

Example how to use it check following github repo:

- https://github.com/Eldorados/script.module.urlresolver